# Unable to get property 'subscribe' of undefined or null reference in ActivatedRoute

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I want to know how to mock ActivatedRoute url.

I am getting current url by using ActivatedRoute

```
this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(url => {
            this.isEdit = false;
            if (url[0].path === 'updatecoc') {
                this.isEdit = true;
            }
        });
```

So I want to mock url in `ActivatedRoute`

I have tried this

```
let fakeActivatedRoute = new MockActivatedRoute();// MockActivatedRoute I have implemented this class from MockActivatedRoute class
fakeActivatedRoute.parent = new MockActivatedRoute();
let urlSegment: UrlSegment[] = [];
 urlSegment.push({ path: "updatecoc", parameters: {} });
 fakeActivatedRoute.url = Observable.of(urlSegment);
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({ { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: fakeActivatedRoute }})
```

But I am getting error:

> unable to get property 'subscribe' of undefined or null reference

I don't know where I am missed. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a better solution for you :

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule],
  // ...
})
  .compileComponents();
```

This will mock your whole routing module, now you can inject your dummy mock into your providers and spy on the functions like so

```
providers: [{provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {}}]
```

And when you test a function calling, let's say, `myMock` (I know it's not in it, it's for the example) :

```
const mock = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
spyOn(mock, 'myMock').and.returnValue(/* what you want */);
// ...

expect(mock.myMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/* params here */);
```

**EDIT** I quickly looked at what url is made of, here is your mock :

```
mock.url = jasmine
  .createSpy()
  .and
  .returnValue(new BehaviorSubject({
    path: 'yout-mocked-path',
    parameters: {/* your mocked parameters */}
  })));
```

Comment: the url accepts only observable objects. how we declare this?

Comment: I typed fast and changed the example for a function. To mock the return of the URL, use `mock.url = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(Observable.of([/* some values here */]));`

Comment: Yes. I want to know what kind of values we need to provide? Because the URL datatype is `Observable<UrlSegement[])`

Comment: You provide the value you want, if you want me to tell what you need to provide, you will need to give me your code, I'm not mocking ActivatedRoute everyday :P

Comment: Error: `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target` because createspy() expecting an argument.

Comment: Errrr `createSpy` doesn't expect an argument ... But I just noticed, since you imported the whole router testing module, simply call this : `mock.url = jasmine
  .createSpy().and.callThrough()`

Comment: see `function createSpy(name: string, originalFn?: Function): Spy;` it expecting an argument.

Comment: All of my spys in my project tend to disagree. For instance : `component['removeMarker'] = jasmine.createSpy();`. But anyway, calling through should work, did you try it ?

Comment: Am getting the same error `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target `

Comment: I also tried `spyOn(activatedRoute, 'url')
            .and.callFake(function () {
                return Observable.of(["updatecoc"]);
            });` till not working

Comment: `callFake` is the same as `returnValue`, except that you have to create a function. But `url` is a property, you need to spy with `jasmine.createSpy` (and give it a name if you must), because the create spy function can spy on non-functions.

Comment: Ok what you  mean by `BehaviorSubject`?? Sorry am new for UI Unit testing. That's why am asking silly questions :(

Comment: No problem ! `BehaviorSubject` is an rxjs subject that returns a value everytime you subscribe to it (even when it's already created). You can find documentation online so I won't explain it to you deeply, sorry ! But when I logged `this.route.url` in my project, it logged a `BehaviorSubject`, meaning that `url` is one. So if you want to mock it, you need to return a value that is typed as a `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: `activatedRoute.url = jasmine
        .createSpy("url")
        .and
        .returnValue(new BehaviorSubject({
            path: 'yout-mocked-path',
            parameters: {/* your mocked parameters */ }
        }));` error. I can't assign `Property _scalar is missing in type Spy`

Comment: Also showing another error : `The Spy is not assignable to type Observable<UrlSegment[]>`. Is it very critical?

Comment: `activatedRoute.url = jasmine .createSpy("url") .and .callThrough()` ?

Comment: Showing the same error `The Spy is not assignable to type Observable<UrlSegment[]>.` . See the property of url data type is `Observable<UrlSegment[]>;` So how can it allow to  provide other types ? see `export declare class ActivatedRoute {
   url: Observable<UrlSegment[]>;,......}`

Comment: Try to make a console log of the url, tell me what it says !

Comment: Am fixing lot of issues arounding this area :(

Comment: It means. It does not allow  make mock dude see https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uyx0.jpg

Comment: :D I meant in your component, make a `console.log(this.activatedRoute.url)`

Comment: Corporate proxy, no access to images ... Behold, I'm creating a project to test the url, I'll keep you updated

Comment: I have update that image in your answer. Once you saw that. then please remove theat image

Comment: `#1` for your effort

Comment: Corportae proxy means I can't access imgur, not that I can't click on links :P